# How to use the reserved words inside the string in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr4

I am a newbie to ANTLR4 and language compilers. I am working on building a language compiler using ANTLR4 Java. I have a small problem with parsing strings. The reserved words/ Tokens are getting matched instead of string. For eg: IF is a keyword token in my lexer but how to use "if" as a string?

```
Lexer file:

lexer grammar testgrammar;

IF              :   I F;
ENDIF           :   E N D I F;
ELSE            :   E L S E;
CASE            :   C A S E;
ENDCASE         :   E N D C A S E;
BREAK           :   B R E A K;
SWITCH          :   S W I T C H;
SUBSTRING       :   S U B S T R I N G;


COMMA             :     ','   ;
SEMI              :     ';' ;
COLON             :     ':'   ;
LPAREN            :     '('   ;
RPAREN            :     ')'   ;
DOT               :     '.' ;// ('.' {$setType(DOTDOT);})?  ;
LCURLY            :     '{' ;
RCURLY            :     '}' ;
AND               :     '&&' ;
OR                :     '||' ;
DOUBLEQUOTES      :     '"'  ;
COMPARATOR        :     '=='| '>=' | '>' | '<' | '<=' | '!=' ;
SYMBOLS           :     '§' | '$' | '%' | '/' | '=' | '?' | '#' | '_' | '@' | '€';
LETTER            :     [A-Za-z\u00e4\u00c4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df];
NUMERICVALUE      :     NUMBER ('.' NUMBER)?;
STRING_LITERAL    :     '\'' ('\'\'' | ~('\''))* '\'';
NOTCONDITION      :     NOT;
OPERATORS         :     OPERATOR;
COMMENT           :     (('/*' .*? '*/') | ('//' ~[\r\n]*)) -> skip;
WS                :     (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ -> skip;

fragment A:('a'|'A');
fragment B:('b'|'B');
fragment C:('c'|'C');
fragment D:('d'|'D');
fragment E:('e'|'E');
fragment F:('f'|'F');
fragment G:('g'|'G');
fragment H:('h'|'H');
fragment I:('i'|'I');
fragment J:('j'|'J');
fragment K:('k'|'K');
fragment L:('l'|'L');
fragment M:('m'|'M');
fragment N:('n'|'N');
fragment O:('o'|'O');
fragment P:('p'|'P');
fragment Q:('q'|'Q');
fragment R:('r'|'R');
fragment S:('s'|'S');
fragment T:('t'|'T');
fragment U:('u'|'U');
fragment V:('v'|'V');
fragment W:('w'|'W');
fragment X:('x'|'X');
fragment Y:('y'|'Y');
fragment Z:('z'|'Z');
fragment NUMBER:[0-9]+;
fragment OPERATOR: ('+'|'-'|'&'|'*'|'~');
fragment NOT: ('!');


grammar:
parser grammar testParser;

symbolCharacters:      (SYMBOLS | operators)     ;


word:
    ( symbolCharacters | LETTER )+
    ;

wordList:
    word+
    ;
```

---

I am not supposed share full grammar. But i have shared enough information i guess. I can understand that the words are formed from LETTERS and Symbol characters. One workaround i can do is making word rule like:

word:
( symbolCharacters | LETTER | IF | SWITCH | CASE | ELSE | BREAK )+
;

I have a lot of tokens. I dont want to add everything individually. Is there any other nice way to accomplish this?

[Valid expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAX4t.png)
[Error expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WMHn.png)

How to make the parser ignore the keywords inside the string?

Comment: Antlr4 doesn't have a complete set of operators for token sets in the parser. Missing are "-"- and ".."-operators, which other parser generators support, and which is used in the Java and C++ specs. But, it does have "|" and "~". You could try to construct the set using these operators. Or, use a semantic predicate a token type range. Aside, you should not define `word : (.......) +;` i.e. '+'-closure of assorted token types then define `wordList : word +;` also with '+'-closure. This is ambiguous. It may cause performance issues with the lookahead computation. Define `word` as `word : ... ;`

Answer (score 1):

Your same grammar does not have the problem you describe:

```
➜ antlr4 testgrammar.g4 

➜ javac *.java

➜ echo "if 'if' endif" | grun testgrammar tokens -tokens
[@0,0:1='if',<IF>,1:0]
[@1,3:6=''if'',<STRING_LITERAL>,1:3]
[@2,8:12='endif',<ENDIF>,1:8]
[@3,14:13='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
```

(perhaps you have inadvertently "corrected" the problem as you trimmed your grammar down, so I'll elaborate a bit.)

In short, during the lexing/tokenization phase of ANTLR parsing your input, ANTLR will, naturally, attempt to match you Lexer rules.  If ANTLR finds a match of multiple rules for the current characters of your input stream, it follows two rules to determine a "winner".

- If a rule matches a longer sequence of input characters, then that rule will be used.
- If two rules match the same number of input characters, then the rule appearing first in your grammar will be used.

In your case, neither *really* comes into play as the grammar, when it reaches the `'`, will attempt to complete the `STRING_LITERAL` rule, and will find a match for the characters `'if'`.  It will never even attempt to match you `IF` lexer rule.

BTW, I did have to correct the `symbolCharacters` parser rule to be

```
symbolCharacters: (SYMBOLS | OPERATORS);
```